# returning vector of arrays from function in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have to return vector from a function. I tried by returning the value and also passing it as reference. but i get junk values.
The below program gives the following output.

```
 **This is the print inside the function**
 1 7 8  
 1 2 3 
 4 5 6 

 **This is the print using the return value /  referenced value outside the function**. 
 1 7 8 
 46980021526656 46980019425190 0 
 1 46980021526656 6

#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void process(vector<unsigned long long int*> &vec)
{
    //vector<unsigned long long int*> vec;
    unsigned long long int a[] ={1,2,3};
    unsigned long long int b[] = {4,5,6};
    vec.push_back(a);
    vec.push_back(b);

    for (int i = 0;i < vec.size();i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
        {
            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        }
    cout << "\n";

//return vec;
}

int main() {
// your code goes here
vector<unsigned long long int*> vec;
unsigned long long int c[] ={1,7,8};
vec.push_back(c);
process(vec);
for (int i = 0;i < vec.size();i++)
{
    for (int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
    {
        cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
cout << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

I dont know what went wrong. I referred many stack overflow posts . But i couldnt find the solution

Please do point out what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: storing arrays from local scope in vec is very bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Standard Library arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void process(vector<array<int, 3>> &vec)
{
    //vector<unsigned long long int*> vec;
    array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
    array<int, 3> b{4, 5, 6};
    vec.push_back(a);
    vec.push_back(b);

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    //return vec;
}
int main()
{
    // your code goes here
    vector<array<int, 3>> vec;
    array<int, 3> c{1, 7, 8};
    vec.push_back(c);
    process(vec);
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The STL has no such facility. The C++ Standard Library, however, recently added it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fixed now. Well it wasn't quite recent per say since C++11.

Comment: 2011 is pretty recent.

Answer (score 6):

> Please do point out what i am doing wrong

your code is :

> ```
> void process(vector<unsigned long long int*> &vec)
> {
>     //vector<unsigned long long int*> vec;
>     unsigned long long int a[] ={1,2,3};
>     unsigned long long int b[] = {4,5,6};
>     vec.push_back(a);
>     vec.push_back(b);
> ```

so *process* memorize in *vec* addresses of local variables *a* and *b*, when you go back in *main* these local variables do not exist anymore, the content they have is undefined/broken so in *main* you write undefined values

`vec.push_back(a);` does not copy *a*, that just pushes the address of *a*

Comment: lol I know, this is not my code, this is his code, I just explain his error

Comment: The question was about correct way of doing this, I guess. Explaining the error itself alone is not an answer imho.

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct. Peeps need to read more carefully before voting angrily.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek No, the question is literally (quoting): "Please do point out what i am doing wrong"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks, I was afraid all people are crazy here

Comment: @bruno Well that's still true 

Comment: I think this one can be bypassed through smart pointers

Comment: @SouyamaDebnath The idea in your answer seems better.